# matplotlib savefig does not output a file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have loaded one column each from two different dataframes and am plotting them on a line graph. The graph pops up on my screen, but my plt.savefig command is not working, as no files are saved.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.plotly as py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# read in LEC
LLEC = pd.read_csv('LLEC_1.csv').transpose()
RLEC = pd.read_csv('RLEC_2.csv').transpose()

#read in DGCA3
LDGCA3=pd.read_csv('LDGCA3_13.csv').transpose()
RDGCA3 = pd.read_csv('RDGCA3_14.csv').transpose()

def plot_betas_left(betaNum):
    betaNum = int(betaNum)

    #plot betas for both ROIs. start with LEC
    ax = LLEC[betaNum].plot()
    # add DGCA3
    LDGCA3[betaNum].plot(ax=ax)
    # label axes
    ax.set_xlabel("precise beta number (0 is first)")
    ax.set_ylabel("beta coefficient value")
    # inset legend
    ax.legend(['LEC', 'DGCA3'])
    plt.savefig('Subj%s_left_LEC_DGCA3.png' % betaNum+1)

plot_betas(3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
>>> "%s" % 12+1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

as you see you have a priority problem between the `%` operator and the `+` operator there:

```
plt.savefig('Subj%s_left_LEC_DGCA3.png' % betaNum+1)
```

`'Subj%s_left_LEC_DGCA3.png' % betaNum` is first computed to a string, then python tries to add `1` to this string, which explains the error (you didn't post any error, but the fact that it doesn't save gives that away)

I would do:

```
plt.savefig('Subj%s_left_LEC_DGCA3.png' % (betaNum+1))
```

or even better:

```
plt.savefig('Subj{}_left_LEC_DGCA3.png'.format(betaNum+1))
```

That said, getting hold of a console where you can see exceptions that your code raises would help greatly.